# How can I make a plot representing connection relationship with python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a plot like this with python, I searched in matplotlib Gallery but can't find any similar one:
[image]

The plot is made based on 2D matrix. For example, I have a 5*5 matrix, symmetric about the diagonal：

```
Connection = np.array([0,0,1,1,1],
                      [0,0,1,0,1],
                      [1,1,0,1,0],
                      [1,0,1,0,0],
                      [1,1,0,0,0])
```

The element represent the connections relationships, if `Connection[ i ][ j ] = 0`, means no connections between `dot i and dot j`. If `Connection[ i ][ j ] = 1`, then there should be a connection line between `dot i and j`

Since it's a bidirectional relation and the matrix is symmetric , if dot 1 has connection with dot 3, then dot 3 should also has connection with dot 1.

For the matrix given, the expected plot should looks like(I made this by powerpoint) :
[image]

How can I make this kind plots?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by networkx package